# What is the correct Selenium syntax to assert that I'm unable to view a particular link/element?

Tags: selenium

I have a Selenium test that is supposed to verify that I'm unable to see a button link unless there is a certain amount of information present on a page such as a pagination link for example. Here is my Selenium assert statement:

```
def test_bottom_links
  load_page('orgs/apache_software')
  $driver.find_element(:xpath => "//a[@id='btn_orgs_see_all_projects']").element? == false
end
```

In my mind this makes sense to me but I receive this error when I run my test:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@id='btn_orgs_see_all_projects']"}
```

The above error is what I want as a passing statement. I don't want Selenium to find this element because it should not be there.

I've also tried this and I get the same error:

```
$driver.find_element(:xpath => "//a[@id='btn_orgs_see_all_projects']").displayed? == false
```

I was wondering what the correct syntax should be to make this test pass. I've referred to these links[assertNotSomething](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html) and [List of Selenium Methods](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/method_list.html). However, these don't have examples of how they are used so I was wondering how someone would write a test like the above. Thanks for any  help offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to `$driver.find_elements` that will return an array without raising an exception. Then you can check for the size of the array to make sure it is empty indicating that the element was not found.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple boolean check method that should work.

```
boolean checkForElementPresence(By locator)
    {
        try {
            driver.findElement(locator);
            return true;
           } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
               return false;
          }
      }
```